# What's the easiest way of populating a collection view cell's label from an array of strings?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Let's say I have an string array like: ["Michael", "James", "Rob"], and I want to populate my 3 cell's text title with these names.

I'm using a UICollectionViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods as follows:

`collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` should return the `count` of your array.

`collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` should return a cell of type `UICollectionViewCell` where you display the correct item. You can get the correct index of the array with `indexPath.item`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol for some object (which can be the `UICollectionViewController` itself) and set it as your view's `dataSource` property.

Something like:

```
class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    myDataArray: [String] = ["data", "goes", "here"]

    override init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(layout)
        self.collectionView?.dataSource = self
    }

    collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) {
        return myDataArray.count
    }

    collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = myDataArray[indexPath.row]
        //use "item" to build your cell
        return myCell
    }

}
```