# unable to print response from api in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have post request type API I use the request.HTTP method = "POST" to hit API

here's my code is

```
var posts = [[String: Any]]()

func apicall() {
    let Url = String(format: "http://example.com")
    guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: Url) else { return }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
           do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any] {
                    self.posts = json["data"] as! [[String : Any]]
                    print("here the data that i want \(self.posts)")
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

now I get the response in JSON and print. now I don't know how to print the JSON in collectionView

here's my collectionView code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CreatGroupCollectionViewCell
    let link = "http://example.com" + posts[indexPath.row]["icons"] as! String
    cell.lbl.text = posts[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
    cell.btn2.downloaded(from: link)
    return cell
}
```

I'm unable to print image on the button and I use extension for this

Comment: You mean populate the collection view? Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43429797/14351818) for the basics

Comment: What does "print the JSON in collectionView" mean? Do you want to represent the JSON in cells in a collection view? Do you know how to make a collection view? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @jnpdx I print the json that I get from API in collection view

Comment: @coceki so you want the same text that gets printed to the console when you do `print` to appear in a collection view? All in one cell?

Comment: @jnpdx yes you are right

Comment: @jnpdx i update the question please check

Comment: I assume you want to show `posts` on the collectionView. Instead of `print(…)` you should notify the CollectionView by calling `collectionView.reloadData()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to reload you collectionView - try this in your do statement

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
   self.collectionView.reloadData()
       }
```